# Grouping elements from two arrays to one element of another array

Tags: javascript, angular

I have three arrays that I need to link to each other in this way:

1. arr1 = ['A', 'A, 'B', 'B' 'C', 'C', 'A', 'C']
2. arr2 = ['a', 'aa', 'b', 'bb', 'c','cc', 'aaa', 'ccc']
3. arr3 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]

I want these arrays to be linked like this: [['A', ['a', 1], ['aa',2], ['aaa', 7]], ['B', ['b', 3], ['bb',4]], ['C', ['c', 5], ['cc',6], ['ccc',8]]]

How can I create this new array? N.B The elements are pushed sequentially so arr1[0] links to arr2[0], arr1[1] links to arr2[1]

Comment: what is the inner link of array 1 and 2? the same letter? or from 2 the same starting letter?

Comment: @NinaScholz it is more like a 'source' for every element of arr2. I edited the question. I removed duplicates from arr1 which made it confusing, apologies. The elements are pushed sequentially so arr1[0] is the source for arr2[0], arr1[1] is the source for arr2[1] and so on..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could group by the first array.

```js
const
    array1 = ['A', 'A', 'B', 'B', 'C', 'C', 'A', 'C'],
    array2 = ['a', 'aa', 'b', 'bb', 'c', 'cc', 'aaa', 'ccc'],
    array3 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8],
    values = [array2, array3],
    result = Object.values(array1.reduce((r, v, i) => {
        r[v] ??= [v];
        r[v].push(values.map(a => a[i]));
        return r;
    }, {}));

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```